# Threaded post V brake pads

Tags: brakes

Looking to replace my Shimano brake pads. What is the difference between M65/T3 and M70/T3 threaded V brake pads?

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned yourself, the M70T3 uses a threaded post, while the M65T3 uses a knurled post that requires a screw on the V-brake or, more commonly, on a cantilever brake. In fact, the M65T3 is sold as a cantilever brake, and it is shorter and chubbier than the M70T3. **If you have a V brake, you shold buy the M70T3.**